# is there a way around the limit of 65K max length for a field using listaggr()?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Using  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html
I noticed in case the aggregation is > than 65K  you get an error

```
Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit code: 8001
```

is there any setting to  return NULL rather than crashing the query?

Comment: I am aware I have to play with the level of aggregation to stay low - but this is quite empiric approach - is there a way to get just NULL? maybe some un-documented redshift cluster setup :)

Comment: Maybe you could try to use distinct to kick out duplicates if it applies (you probably did already) or maybe split it into smaller groups to make the listagg not concat 65k. I don't know if this is possible though, because I can't see the full Query and how the data structure is.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is the max size of a varchar data type. As for work arounds it will depend on what you are looking to achieve and what other approaches will meet the need.